# SIGSEGV Error while running function in C

Tags: c, function, struct, typedef

i begginer at c programing and while i am runing my C program i got strange error:

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000559625ce4a56 in inputNewCountry (cordinateOfCountry=...) at /home/david/CLionProjects/untitled/Countries.c:40
40    newCountry->cordinateOfCountry.xLeft=cordinateOfCountry.xLeft;

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

the code of my function:

```
Country* inputNewCountry(cordinate cordinateOfCountry)
{
  Country *newCountry;
  newCountry->cordinateOfCountry.xLeft=cordinateOfCountry.xLeft;
    newCountry->cordinateOfCountry.xRight=cordinateOfCountry.xRight;
  newCountry->cordinateOfCountry.yLeft=cordinateOfCountry.yLeft;
    newCountry->cordinateOfCountry.yRight=cordinateOfCountry.yRight;
  newCountry->cities=NULL;
  newCountry->numberOfCities=0;
  return newCountry;
}
```

"struch cordinate":

```
typedef struct cordinate
{
    int xLeft,yLeft;
    int xRight,yRight;
}cordinate;
```

i dont have any idea what i am doing wrong, can someone please help?

Comment: `newCountry` must be allocated before you can set its fields.

Comment: `Country *newCountry;` creates an uninitialized pointer variable. `newCountry->...` then tries to dereference this pointer, but it's not pointing anywhere. Undefined behavior.

Comment: `Country *newCountry = malloc(sizeof(Country));`

Answer (score 1):

```
Country *newCountry;
```

here you define an uninitialized pointer variable.

```
newCountry->cordinateOfCountry.xLeft=[...]
```

here (in the next line) you write data to an offset (calculated by `cordinateOfCountry.xLeft`) to this uninitialized pointer variable, a.k.a. you are writing data to a random point in memory.

You should allocate memory for newCountry, for example with the `stdlib.h` function `malloc`:

```
Country *newCountry = malloc(sizeof(Country));
```

Remember to `free` any allocated memory this way.

You could also allocate a global variable (but be careful since then calling the function more than once will overwrite the data):

```
Country globalCountry;

Country inputNewCountry(cordinate cordinateOfCountry)
{
    Country *newCountry = &globalCountry;
    [...]
```

You can hide the global variable to only be visible *inside* of the function:

```
Country inputNewCountry(cordinate cordinateOfCountry)
{
    static Country hiddenGlobalCountry; // Other functions cannot see hiddenGlobalCountry, but it still acts like a global variable
    // Note that just Country hiddenGlobalCountry won't work, since such a variable will be destroyed once the function exits (making it little better than writing to uninitialized memory)
    Country *newCountry = &hiddenGlobalCountry;
    [...]
```

Or you could simply return a Country instead:

```
Country inputNewCountry(cordinate cordinateOfCountry)
{
  Country newCountry;
  newCountry.cordinateOfCountry.xLeft=cordinateOfCountry.xLeft;
  newCountry.cordinateOfCountry.xRight=cordinateOfCountry.xRight;
  newCountry.cordinateOfCountry.yLeft=cordinateOfCountry.yLeft;
  newCountry.cordinateOfCountry.yRight=cordinateOfCountry.yRight;
  newCountry.cities=NULL;
  newCountry.numberOfCities=0;
  return newCountry;
}
```